# Зачем var app = app || {} в начале пишут?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Зачем в начале скрипта пишут `var app = app || {};` ? [Ссылка на весь файл](https://github.com/tastejs/todomvc/blob/gh-pages/examples/react/js/app.jsx).

P.S. Можно ли подключать JSX скрипты (чтобы они потом работали) без помощи сторонних библиотек? Например, через `<script type="text/jsx"></script>` ?

Comment: Заголовок  поправте пожалуйста, а то совсем не информативный.
В PS у вас похоже новый вопрос.

Comment: Для P.S. - нет, нельзя.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> `var app = app || {};`

Таким образом, избегают переопределения уже инициализированного объекта, при множественной загрузке разных модулей приложения.

Эквивалент:

```
if (!window.app) { // Если app не определена
  window.app = {}; // Инициализируем её объектом
}
```

Остальные скрипты будут работать с уже определённым объектом, расширяя и дополняя его.